# How to break while loop when two conditions are true - Calculator

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm building my first calculator. Trying to implement While loop to get a number through user input. I want the While to break once user put a number.

```
num1 = raw_input("Add mumber one:  " )
try:
  input = int(num1)

except ValueError:
  print "This is not a number"

  attempt = 0
  while type(num1) != int and attempt < 5:
    num1 = raw_input("Add Number one again:  " )
    attempt += 1
  break
  print "You are not putting number. So, goodbuy"



operation = raw_input("Add Operator:  ")
```

Comment: use `if` conditions inside loops to break.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for _ in range(5):
    num1 = unicode(raw_input("Add number one:  "))
    if num1.isnumeric():
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, however, I am new into the coding and wondering what mistake I am doing in my code that is not working? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Another method you can try is to have `num1` and do the following in the `while` loop:

```
if type(num1) is int:
    break
```

What this does is check the type of the variable `num1`. If it is an integer, `int`, then it breaks out of the `while` loop.

> I want the While to break once user put a number.

You already are doing that in the condition for your `while` loop by having `type(num) != int` so your `while` loop should stop after the user enters an integer.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, however, I am new into the coding and wondering what mistake I am doing in my code that is not working? Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank for that, but it is not consider that condition type(num1) != int at all. I am wondering why?

Comment: I don't know why either. I just searched it up and you are using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors here:

```
while type(num1) != int and attempt < 5:
    num1 = raw_input("Add Number one again:  " )
    attempt += 1
break
```

The `break` statement shoud be inside the loop, but the indentation is wrong. As you write, it is after the loop (hence useless). Also, when you read from standard input, you always get a string even if it is a number. So when you check `type(num1) != int` this is always false. You must convert `num1` with `int()` each time you read from standard input, not only the first time:

```
while True:
    num1 = raw_input("Add Number one again:  " )
    try:
        input = int(num1)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "This is not a number"
        if attempt == 5:
            break
        attempt += 1
```

Here I try to convert to an integer the string read from stdin. If it works, I break the loop immediately. If it does not work (the except clause) I check how many attempts have been done, and break the loop if the attempts are equal to 5.